# Acronis TrueImage for full system restore

Tags: acronis

I want to install a 64bit version of Vista on my Dell Inspiron 1525 but before doing that I wan to be sure I have a full image of my existing system, in case of problems.

I have Acronis Trueimage installed that makes an image of my system.  But I don't know for sure that I can actually restore my full system with that image?

How does Acronis manage to copy files that are locked by the system when it makes an image?

Any answers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acronis uses its own driver to create point in time snapshots. Then it does a sector based backup based on that snapshot. From their [web site](http://www.acronis.com/resource/tech-talk/2003/disk-imaging-2-technology.html):

> Acronis solves the task of copying
>   open Windows files by effectively
>   freezing a moment of time. A special
>   filter driver layers between file
>   system drivers and volume drivers,
>   allowing the software to create and
>   backup consistent views of all files,
>   including open files. The driver is
>   installed above the volume drivers so
>   it can see all the read and write
>   requests passing to a volume — or
>   partition.